# Dual nature of data in Java

Tags: java

I have a class `X`. It has two attributes `a` and `b`. In some scenarios, equality of objects of `X` will be based on equality of `a`, and in some based on that of `b`. I wanted to know the best way to model this data.

I can't simply have two equals functions based on some flag because I use a lot of sets and lists, so I must override `equals()`. This is what I have in mind:

1. An interface `X`, which has two implementations `Xa` and `Xb`. Problem is, I will need to convert between `Xa` and `Xb`, and I expect to have hundreds of instances, so creating new copies would be expensive.
2. Since equality based on `a` is expected to occur most of the time, implement `equals()` comparing `a`. When equality based on `b` is required, just write a separate method for it. Problem is, I have to re-invent the wheel for comparing sets and lists.

What are the pros and cons of the above? Is there any other alternative?

Is the class `X` flawed in the first place? Can I implement this in a better way?

Comment: Define `Comparator`s and apply as appropriate?

Comment: For the last question: it is possible. We'd need more info to be sure. The fact that it's mostly based on `a` leads me to believe that you might want to redesign it.

Comment: @chrylis: Defining `Comparator`s wouldn't help because I mostly need equality for `Set`s and `List`s.

@keyser: I have considered the semantics of `X`, and I can see no way around it... What info do you need?

Comment: We'd need enough to be able to draw the same, or different, conclusions ourselves.

Comment: `I expect to have hundreds of instances` you don't really have that much data, any solution you do is probably going to be fast enough.

Answer (score 3):

## Solution 0: Refactoring

The first thing I would like to suggest is to consider re-designing your object hierarchy.  The situation you have described sounds not very clean, though we know little about the actual problem you are trying to model from the information you have provided.

## Solution 1: “Switch” Polymorphism

Taking what you have said as firm requirements, I can think of the following – not particularly pretty – solution.  The basic idea is that each instance of an `X` object gets a flag that tells its “gender”.  Converting between genders is then merely a matter of assigning a single word.  Be aware, however, that this also increases your object size by one word.  If you have many small objects, the additional overhead might be significant.  (In the toy example below, it is as high as one third and in this case, I'd definitely prefer creating a new object of type `Xa` or `Xb` only when needed.)  Depending on how expensive your other equality comparisons and hash code computations are, the additional overhead for the case selection might also be noticeable, though probably acceptable.

The class below is crafted such that it meets all contracts I'm aware of and can be used in any collection and converted freely back and forth.  However, the gender of an object must not be touched while it is contained in any collection and a collection may only contain `X`s of a particular gender.  As you can see, we are slowly departing from object orientation and have to manage our own invariants.  The compiler cannot help us enforce them.  This should be enough to raise a big red flag.

```
public final class X implements Comparable<X> {

    public static enum Genders { A, B };

    private Genders gender;

    private final String a;

    private final Integer b;

    public X(final String a, final Integer b, final Genders gender) {
        if (a == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("a");
        }
        if (b == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("b");
        }
        if (gender == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("gender");
        }
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public Genders getGender() {
        return this.gender;
    }

    public void setGender(final Genders gender) {
        if (gender == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("gender");
        }
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object other) {
        if (other instanceof X) {
            final X otherX = (X) other;
            if (this.gender == otherX.gender) {
                switch (this.gender) {
                case A:
                    return this.a.equals(otherX.a);
                case B:
                    return this.b.equals(otherX.b);
                default:
                    throw new AssertionError("unexpected gender");
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        switch (this.gender) {
        case A:
            return this.a.hashCode();
        case B:
            return this.b.hashCode();
        default:
            throw new AssertionError("unexpected gender");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final X other) {
        // It seems acceptable to allow the case that
        // this.gender != other.gender here.
        switch (this.gender) {
        case A:
            return this.a.compareTo(other.a);
        case B:
            return this.b.compareTo(other.b);
        default:
            throw new AssertionError("unexpected gender");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("{a: \"%s\", b: %d, gender: %s}",
                             this.a, this.b, this.gender);
    }

}
```

Here is a small demo how to use the type.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public final class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Set<X> theAs = new HashSet<>();
        final Set<X> theBs = new TreeSet<>();
        theAs.add(new X("alpha", 1, X.Genders.A));
        theAs.add(new X("beta",  1, X.Genders.A));
        theAs.add(new X("gamma", 2, X.Genders.A));
        theAs.add(new X("delta", 2, X.Genders.A));
        System.out.println("These are the As:\n");
        for (final X x : theAs) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        System.out.println();
        {
            final Iterator<X> iter = theAs.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                final X x = iter.next();
                iter.remove();  // remove before changing gender
                x.setGender(X.Genders.B);
                theBs.add(x);
            }
        }
        theBs.add(new X("alpha", 3, X.Genders.B));
        theBs.add(new X("alpha", 4, X.Genders.B));
        System.out.println("These are the Bs:\n");
        for (final X x : theBs) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
These are the As:

{a: "alpha", b: 1, gender: A}
{a: "delta", b: 2, gender: A}
{a: "beta", b: 1, gender: A}
{a: "gamma", b: 2, gender: A}

These are the Bs:

{a: "alpha", b: 1, gender: B}
{a: "delta", b: 2, gender: B}
{a: "alpha", b: 3, gender: B}
{a: "alpha", b: 4, gender: B}
```

## Solution 2: Decorator Pattern

If you can live (and I'm pretty sure you can) with the overhead of a single `new` per object “conversion”, a much cleaner and less error-prone solution would be to use [*decorators*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Let's start by defining an interface for your type.  (Yours will probably be much more sophisticated than this toy example.)

```
public interface X {

    public String getA();

    public Integer getB();
}
```

Next, we provide a base implementation of that interface that does everything except taking a stand on comparison.  Note that the class is (can be) immutable (and `final` in particular).  Since I'm not overriding `equals` and `hashCode` and don't even bother to implement `Comparable`, instances of this “base” class will have identity comparison semantics inherited from `Object`.  That's just what we want (see later).

```
public final class BasicX implements X {

    private final String a;

    private final Integer b;

    public BasicX(final String a, final Integer b) {
        if (a == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("a");
        }
        if (b == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("b");
        }
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public String getA() {
        return this.a;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getB() {
        return this.b;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("{a: \"%s\", b: %d}", this.a, this.b);
    }

    // Note: No implementation of equals() and hasCode().
}
```

With all the business logic in place, we can now turn to our decorators.  We will define two of them: `Xa` and `Xb`.  They'll delegate everything (which isn't much in this contrived example) to their contained `X` instance except that they'll provide appropriate `equals` and `hashCode` implementations and implement `Comparable`.

Since the delegating logic is the same for both decorators, I'll factor the common code out into an intermediate package-private class.

```
abstract class DecoratedX implements X {

    private final X x;

    protected DecoratedX(final X x) {
        if (x == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("x");
        }
        this.x = x;
    }

    protected final X getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    @Override
    public final String getA() {
        return this.x.getA();
    }

    @Override
    public final Integer getB() {
        return this.x.getB();
    }

    @Override
    public final String toString() {
        return this.x.toString();
    }
}
```

This reduces the code inside `Xa` and `Xb` just to the comparison logic, which is unique in each class.  Note that `Xa` and `Xb` can be `final`.

```
public final class Xa extends DecoratedX implements X, Comparable<Xa> {

    public Xa(final X x) {
        super(x);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object other) {
        if (other instanceof Xa) {
            final Xa otherXa = (Xa) other;
            return this.getA().equals(otherXa.getA());
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.getA().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final Xa other) {
        return this.getA().compareTo(other.getA());
    }
}
```

I'm probably going to annoy you with the (admittedly somewhat repetitive) code for `Xb` but for the sake of completeness, here it is.

```
final class Xb extends DecoratedX implements X, Comparable<Xb> {

    public Xb(final X x) {
        super(x);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object other) {
        if (other instanceof Xb) {
            final Xb otherXb = (Xb) other;
            return this.getB().equals(otherXb.getB());
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.getB().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final Xb other) {
        return this.getB().compareTo(other.getB());
    }
}
```

And there we go.  Putting it all together, we can do even cooler things than before.  Notice how we can now have *the same object* (although wrapped (decorated) in two cases) in three different collections at the same time with different comparison semantics.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public final class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final List<X> theXs = new ArrayList<>();
        final Set<Xa> theXas = new HashSet<>();
        final Set<Xb> theXbs = new TreeSet<>();
        theXs.add(new BasicX("alpha", 1));
        theXs.add(new BasicX("alpha", 1));
        theXs.add(new BasicX("beta", 2));
        theXs.add(new BasicX("beta", 3));
        theXs.add(new BasicX("gamma", 2));
        theXs.add(new BasicX("delta", 3));
        for (final X x : theXs) {
            theXas.add(new Xa(x));
            theXbs.add(new Xb(x));
        }
        System.out.println("These are the As:\n");
        for (final X x : theXas) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("These are the Bs:\n");
        for (final X x : theXbs) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
These are the As:

{a: "alpha", b: 1}
{a: "delta", b: 3}
{a: "beta", b: 2}
{a: "gamma", b: 2}

These are the Bs:

{a: "alpha", b: 1}
{a: "beta", b: 2}
{a: "beta", b: 3}
```

Also note that this design is type-safe: The compiler simply won't let us have an `Xb` object in a collection of `Xa`s.  In the example, I have created the `Xa`s and `Xb`s directly from the `BasicX`s.  If you want to “turn an `Xa` into an `Xb`” or vice versa, the code would be of course

```
Xb a2b(final Xa xa) {
    return new Xb(xa.getX());
}
```

and

```
Xa b2a(final Xb xb) {
    return new Xa(xb.getX());
}
```

for the reverse.  You'll have to make the `DecoratedX.getX()` method `public` for this to actually work.  (Technically, you could also stick an `Xa` into an `Xb`: it *is an* `X`, after all.  While this would totally work, and is appropriate in other applications of the decorator pattern, the useless layers of indirection would soon become obnoxious in this case and are easily avoidable.)

Comment: For the decorator pattern, you may want to be careful to avoid twice wrapping the object. You'll need to make sure you have the original object when constructing the decorator. Also, you may want to be careful to avoid having duplicate decorators for the same instance. If that is a concern, you would want to use a factory function to construct the decorator, which should return an existing decorator instance, but then you'd need to be careful to use weak references to allow the object to be garbage collected.

Comment: @LieRyan As discussed in the last paragraph, multiple layers of wrapping do work, but they might harm performance and ain't pretty if easily avoidable.  Having multiple “views” (through different decorators) on the same object (as in the code example), on the other hand, I consider as a handy feature of the decorator approach.  If the objects – at least like in this example and as I always advise to – are immutable, it really doesn't matter but it might be useful even with mutable objects.  But here we really reach the point where more information about the OP's context is needed.